# Change author and date for the change list

Tags: tfs

My team migrated to TFS2013. But unfortunately we missed the author and date. So all change lists are from the same author and on the same date. This is super annoying since I using annotate and history every day.

Is the any API or command line tool to change author and date on change lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tfs API to achieve it. Use the Properties  **Owner** and **CreationDate** in Changeset Class. 
More information from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset(v=vs.120).aspx

A sample code about changeset

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
            VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));


    var history = vcs.QueryHistory("$/<BranchFolder>",
                new ChangesetVersionSpec(lastChangesetIDofLabel),
                 1,
                 RecursionType.Full,
                 string.Empty,
                 new ChangesetVersionSpec(lastChangesetIDofLabel+1),
                 VersionSpec.Latest,
                 int.MaxValue,
                 true,
                 false);

            foreach (Changeset changeset in history)
            {
               foreach(Change change in changeset.Changes)
               {                   
                   changeset.Owner = @"admin";
                   changeset.CreationDate = DateTime.Parse("2015-11-01 17:34:42");                       
               }
            }
```

Comment: This sample code does not persist the changes to the database. Adding changeset.Update(); did not fix it. In my case, the only value I need to update is the OwnerDisplayName. I changed it in the Identity table using SQL Server Management Studio, but somehow that did not affect the value retrieved for the old Changesets. Still a mystery.